# How do partitions work in Spark Streaming?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, rdd, spark-streaming-kafka

I am working on performance improvement of a spark streaming application.

How the partition works in streaming environment. Is is same as loading a file in into spark or all the time it creates only one partition, making it work in only one core of the executor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Spark Streaming (not Structured) the partitioning works exactly as you know it from working with `RDD`s. You can easily check the number of partitions with

```scala
rdd.getNumPartitions
```

As you have also tagged *spark-streaming-kafka* it is worth mentioning that the number of partitions in your input DStream will match the number of partitions in the Kafka topic you are consuming.

In general, for RDDs, there are the [HashPartitioner](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/HashPartitioner.html) and the [RangePartitioner](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/RangePartitioner.html) for repartitions strategies available. You could use the `HashPartitioner` by

```scala
rdd.partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(2))
```

where `rdd` is a *key-value paired* RDD and `2` is the number of partitions.

Compared to the Structured API, RDDs also have the advantage to apply custom partitioners. For this, you can extend the `Partitioner` class and override the methods `numPartitions` and `getPartitions` like in the example given below:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.Partitioner

class TablePartitioner extends Partitioner {
  override def numPartitions: Int = 2
  override def getPartition(key: Any): Int = {
    val tableName = key.asInstanceOf[String]
    if(tableName == "foo") 0 // partition count start at 0
    else 1
  }
}
```